# Shopware 5 - How to pass data from Subscriber Method to ExtJS

Tags: php, symfony, extjs, symfony4, shopware

Not sure if this more related to ExtJS or Shopware but... is there any way i can intercept this response and add something to it?

I have overridden the method `article_crud.js` controller, but i want to pass some additional thing from my subscriber method to ExtJS and show growl message on that condition. But the response always contains either `'yes'` `'no'` `'cancel'`[image]

[image]